# iOS App built with SDK 16.1 but base SDK set to 14.0 in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Got an email from Apple to bump the sdk version and in the email they say "This app was built with the iOS 16.1 SDK.".

However, in Xcode (15.2) I see that

- iOS Deployment Target = 14.0
- Minimum deployments (IOS) = 14.0
- Podfile `platform :ios, '14.0'`

How is it building with `16.1` and not `14.0`?

Note: the app is built with React Native, but i don't think it should change anything.

Comment: Being built with iOS 16.1 would normally mean you used Xcode 14.1. With Xcode 15.2 it would build with iOS 17.2. 14.0 is simply the deployment target, not the SDK used for building.

Comment: Wow that makes no sense to me, so xcode version determines the SDK? 
Also, the app wasn't built by a local machine but by CI, so then it would depend on what version of the CI xcodebuild?

Comment: Yes, the toolchain, including the SDK, depends on the Xcode version.  You will need to look at your CI file and the CI platform documentation to select the required version of Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @HangarRash for pointing me in the right direction.

The `SDK version` and the `Deployment Target` are two different things. What determines the SDK version that will be used to build is the version of your XCode installed on the machine. More information can be [found here](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).

In my case, the app is built with `fastlane/gym` on a Github hosted machine. Digging in the configuration file for the CI action I found the following:

```
  build-ios:
    runs-on: macos-12
    steps:
      ...
      - uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
        with:
          xcode-version: '14.1'
```

Knowing the XCode version is `14.1` this explains why the app is built using SDK `16.1` as per the apple docs pasted above.